# MSBuild disable build step and just run code analysis

Tags: visual-c++, code-analysis

Is there a property for MSBuild that disables the build step and just runs the code analysis for a given vcxproj/sln?

I want to automatically run a code analysis each night without running the build itself.

Comment: Switched to visual-c++ tag, as C#/VB.NET code analysis depends on build where build cannot be skipped.